# Rename the Excel Sheet Name in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, office-automation

VS 2008 / C#.

On passing the File path of a Spreadsheet, i need to rename the Sheet.

How to rename the Sheet1 of the Excel Sheet as "ABC".

We exporting an Excel Sheet to the SQL Database.  Records in the Excel Sheet are manually edited and updated by end user. Column Values can have different datatypes.

By default, a Spread Sheet will have three Sheets as Sheet1, Sheet2,Sheet3.

End Users, usually work on Sheet1. We need to maintain a static name for this Sheet1 which helps us to Export the Sheet1 to SQL Database.

If we renamed the Sheet1 as ABC, we are maintaining the same Name. We cant export default sheet as like that. Because, End users may change their name or stick with default name on it.

In order to avoid confusion, we decided to rename the Sheet1 of the Spread Sheet.

Comment: Any reason to degrade my question ??

Comment: A Google search on the term 'c# rename excel worksheet' yielded several possible answers. Although I myself would be reluctant to downvote in this situation, perhaps the downvoter is expressing his concern that the answer to your question is readily available from many sources.

Comment: I'm not the one who downgraded, but I'm guessing it's because you didn't give us much information to go on.  What have you tried?  How far have you gotten?  If you're using Excel automation objects and can get a reference to the specific sheet, you can call sheet.SetName("ABC").  But Excel automation may not be appropriate in all scenarios.  If you provide a little more background, I'll try to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### C# 3.0

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;

string laPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("C:\\ExcelSheet.xls");
xlBook = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(laPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlSheet.Name = "CIAO";
xlBook.Save();
xl.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```

### C# 4.0+

The difference is: no more `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` and using DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime)

```
using System.IO;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Then

```
var excelFile = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\ExcelSheet.xls");
var excel = new Excel.Application();
var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Item[1]; // 1 is the first item, this is NOT a zero-based collection
sheet.Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
workbook.Save();
excel.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```